# Crowdsourcing how to tag old and new Delta Green questions

Tags: discussion, tags

There's a new tag, [new-delta-green](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-delta-green). Since what's *new* is relative to *now* and now keeps changing, that's obviously not a good long-term tag. I'm having a hard time deciding on a replacement though.

So the situation is that the *new* Delta Green is a full-fledge roleplaying game. The *old* Delta Green is a line of setting supplements for *Call of Cthulhu*.

In considering the different ways we disambiguate tags, none of them strike me as sufficiently self-explanatory and “good tagging practice” to be obviously the way to go, leaving me unwilling to just mod-change them unilaterally. The ways I thought of are:

- [delta-green](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green)/[delta-green-setting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-setting) (changing both). This would give primacy to the RPG itself, but these wouldn't get used right: [dg] would keep getting used for both, and [dg-setting] would *also* get used for both.
- [delta-green-2016](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-2016)/[delta-green](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green) (leaving old alone). Old one would get used for the RPG too. It also implies that there was a pre-2016 RPG, so it would be a confusing pair.
- [delta-green-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-rpg)/[delta-green-coc](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-coc)* (changing both). This is clear enough and they likely wouldn't get used wrong, but it's not called “Delta Green RPG” so that rubs me the wrong way. But maybe it's the best of the lot?

  (* Notably, [delta-green-call-of-cthulhu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-call-of-cthulhu) fits in our tag limit. It might be worth considering instead of [delta-green-coc](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-coc), but it looks to me like the *CoC* part might overwhelm the *DG* part. On the other hand, perhaps it should — to emphasise that old DG is a sub-topic of CoC, we might consider [call-of-cthulhu-delta-green](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-cthulhu-delta-green)?)

How should we tag *Delta Green* the RPG and Delta Green the *Call of Cthulhu* setting supplement line?

Comment: How is the delta green community referring to these? That's been a major guidepost for us in the past.

Comment: "delta-green-for-call-of-cthulhu" also fits within our tag limit, names both products, and labels the relationship.

Comment: @doppelgreener I'm not sure. I haven't done much digging, and I know the online DG community isn't that large. I'm hoping our local experts can help us there.

Comment: @doppelgreener Might want to suggest that pairing to see about votes.

Comment: good point, done!

Answer (score 11):

I agree with the principle of not having a generic "delta green" tag left to be confusing and ambiguous.

I suggest we go with [delta-green-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-rpg) and [delta-green-for-call-of-cthulhu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-for-call-of-cthulhu).

[delta-green-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-rpg) is the same as what you brought up.

[delta-green-for-call-of-cthulhu](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-for-call-of-cthulhu) is better by a hair than the other options for this edition, I think. It comes in at 31 characters (just within our 35 character limit) and clearly establishes the relationship. It also puts "delta green" first, which is the product people are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

[delta-green-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-rpg)/[delta-green-coc](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-coc) (changing both) Looks the best to me.

- This clearly disambiguates the 2 products.
- It forces tag users to pick one or the other, there is no default [delta-green](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green) to mistakenly choose.
- Which tag to use on a given question will be obvious (the acronym and the tag description make it clear)
- I think that both tags will be findable by someone searching for them, ie., someone googling "Delta Green Call of Cthulhu" will find and recognize "delta-green-coc".

Comment: I'm not sure that "coc" is going to immediately be parsed as "Call of Cathulu" by readers or by OPs if they are not aware of the difference between the two products.

Answer (score 5):

[delta-green-rpg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delta-green-rpg)/[call-of-cthulhu-delta-green](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/call-of-cthulhu-delta-green) leaves the least scope for confusion.

Comment: This most clearly disambiguates between the standalone newer product and the original subsidiary project.

Answer (score 0):

If the community actually uses 'new delta green' to refer to the new system, then that's not actually a problem in naming.  Consider 'world of darkness' which has two major editions, the newer of which is actually referred to as NWOD/"New World of Darkness" by the community.  It's true the name will be a bit humorous once a new line is released (if ever), but that doesn't make the term ambiguous or unclear.

See also: Modernist Philosophy & (separately) Art, Pre-History, New Age, New York, New School Hip Hop, etc.

That said, the community and author does seem to use 'delta green rpg' rather than 'new delta green', at least as far as I can tell.  Nonetheless, the problem with the tag is that it doesn't accurately reflect what people will search when looking for questions about that topic rather than that it calls itself 'new' and can't be new forever.

Comment: It does make the *old* tag unclear though.